# Server.xml for WAS

Tags: java, maven, rad, websphere-8

I am looking for a configuration file in websphere 8.5.1 which holds all the server settings like datasources, buses, queues etc. I am aware of server.xml which is present for every server instance at cell level but it does not have all the settings. 
Please help me with some suggestion. I am looking for this file as I want to configure a maven integration test with websphere8.5.1.

So, in order to run these tests I would need some file to get the configurations from.
Basically i am trying to replicate a maven integration test with glassfish where domain.xml was used in the maven integration script pom.xml to configure all the resources.

Answer (score 4):

For WebSphere "full Profile" (as opposed to "Liberty Profile"), there is no single file. All that information is spread across many files.

Comment: True, though you may be able to pull that information out of a running server using an admin script.  See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/samples/SampleScripts.html But that's going to be a bit of an uphill climb.

Answer (score 0):

The information on datasources will be in resource.xml. However, there is a resources.xml file at every scope ie at cell level , cluster level, node level and JVM level. So based on where datasource is defined the correct resource.xml can be used. Sib configuration will be created in the PROFILE_HOME/config/cells//buses

VG, opinions are my own and not those of my employer

Answer (score 0):

There is a PropertiesBasedConfiguration command group from WAS 7 onwards which can let you extract your config to a single file but there are some limitations too.

You can check below links to get more info on same:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rxml_7propbasedconfig.html

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0904_chang/0904_chang.html